# list the link files of a process

Tags: process, libraries, dynamic-linking, static-linking

Saying that there is a running process named `a`.

Is it possible to list all of the lib files that `a` needs, including static link files and dynamic link files (`.a`, `.so`)?

Comment: What does it mean to identify the static libraries used by a running process?

Comment: Doesn't `/proc/${PID}/maps` show all loaded files in memory, besides other things?

Comment: `lsof` for running processes, `ldd` for the executable commands, would show the libraries loaded.